# Compiling data from multiple locked excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a tool for monitoring time, I have about 10 employees that will be using these. So I created a spreadsheet for each one and they require a password to open. Each spreadsheet contains a data tab with the same fields. Is there anyway I can compile all that data to make certain pivot charts that contain all the information in each of the datasheets?

Comment: Yes that is possible. That will require that they give you their password or at least give you authorization to open their files.

Answer (score 0):

Using this line you would

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("xxxxx").UnProtect password:="xxxxxx"
```

you would be able to unlock the sheets.

If you loop through them all using something like

```
Dim ws as worksheet

For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.UnProtect Password:="xxxx"
    ' What ever you want to do with the data


    ws.Protect Password:="xxxx"
next ws
```

Then you'd be able to unlock each sheet in the workbook, extract the data, then lock it again.